# Execute DropDownList event generically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a utility method that will select an item from a dropdown list and I'd like to add the ability to trigger the selected index changed event (if requested).

How can I verify that this event exists and then execute it?

Example Page Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dropDownListEditMyControl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(dropDownListEditMyControl_SelectedIndexChanged);
    Utilities.SelectedItemInDropdown(dropDownListMyControl);
}

protected void dropDownListEditMyControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do something special
}
```

Utility Code:

```
public static void SelectItemInDropdown(DropDownList dropDown, int? value, bool triggerChangeEvent)
    {
        if (value.HasValue)
        {
            ListItem li = dropDown.Items.FindByValue(value.Value.ToString());
            if (li != null)
            {
                dropDown.ClearSelection();
                li.Selected = true;

                if (triggerChangeEvent)
                {
                    if (dropDown.SelectedIndexChanged != null)
                    {
                        dropDown.SelectedIndexChanged(dropDown, new EventArgs());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue is with checking to see if the dropdown has the selected index changed event and then calling it (it doesn't compile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast `dropDown` as `IPostBackDataHandler` and call `RaisePostDataChangedEvent`.

If `dropDown` doesn't have an event handler, no exception is risen, so you don't have to check it beforehand.